# Wordpress and buddypress advice

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a website that I want to setup so that users can register for the site but the administrator of the site will have the final say on whether or not they can be a member of the site or not.

I am running Wordpress 3.0.1 and Buddypress 1.2.5, buddypress is used to register the user, so I assume it will need to be a buddypress plugin that is used to allow or deny the user. I have searched and searched and cannot come up with any plugin that replicates this functionality. Are there any out there, or anything that gives a similar experience?

Many Thanks To Anyone That Helps,

sea_1987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a BP component for Allow / Deny User:

http://webdevstudios.com/support/wordpress-plugins/buddypress-registration-options/

The description:

A WordPress BuddyPress plugin that allows for new member moderation, if moderation is turned on from the admin settings page, any new members will be blocked from interacting with any buddypress elements (except editing their own profile and uploading their avatar) and will not be listed in any directory until an administrator approves or denies their account.

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed a thorough research exercise on this, with the same requirement in mind.  The sad truth of the matter is that most of the plugins that supposedly give you this functionality do not work fully and properly.  I tried a number of plugins including:

- Buddypress Registration Options
- Absolute Privacy
- Angsuman’s Authenticated WordPress Plugin
- BuddyPress Private Community

All of these failed to give me bulletproof security. They largely seemed to block standard WordPress pages, but didn't block public access to the Activity, Members, Groups and other sections.  Other issues were simply getting it to work with WP 3.0.1. I found I had to dig into the plugin code and hack it to get a decent result.

Finally, I settled on a plugin called "registered-users-only-2".  This totally blocks users who are not registered.  However, it doesn't give you moderation functionality.

I hope this helps your quest.